# When does a complete bipartite graph contains a Hamiltonian cicle?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, hamiltonian-path

¿Is there a way to know when does a complete bipartite graph $K_(n,m) $  contains a Hamiltonian cicle? I was trying to figure a secure way to prove a Hamiltonian Cycle on those kind of Graphs, using some theorems:

$ \bullet \quad \forall v \exists V \quad d(v)\ge 2 $ (degrees of every vertex must me $\ge $ 2)

$ \bullet \quad \forall S \subset S ,S \neq V, S \neq  \varnothing \quad comp(G-S)  \le \left\lvert S \right\rvert $

$ \bullet \quad$ G=(X,Y) Bipartite    $\quad  \left\lvert X \right\rvert =\left\lvert Y \right\rvert$

But every one of those theorems have Counter-Cases  where they are not valid, so i just want to know if there is a secure way to determinate if a complete bipartite Graph is Hamiltonian.

Help really aprecciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes when $n=m$.

No when $n\ne m$. A Hamiltonian cycle must alternate between vertices
on each "side" of the bipartition, so there must be an equal number of each,
that is $m=n$, for such a cycle to exist.

Comment: In addition, it contains a hamiltonian path if $|m-n|\leq1$.

Comment: There's also the sneaky edge case, $n=m=1$ doesn't contain a Hamiltonian cycle.